# computing with nan's with numpy's ma module

Tags: python, numpy

I do not understand the behavior of this `numpy.ma.max` (min, mean, etc.)

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.ma.array([0,np.nan,1])
np.ma.max(arr)
-> nan
```

I thought this was supposed to return a value excluding `nan`'s? The only way I can get a real value is

```
np.nanmax(np.asarray(arr))
```

Is this right, or am I using `numpy.ma.max` incorrectly?

Comment: Maybe you just could use nanmean from scipy.stats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the mask:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.ma.array([0,np.nan,1])
print(np.ma.max(arr))
# >>>nan    # since there is no mask
marr = np.ma.masked_array([0,np.nan,1], np.isnan(arr))
print(np.ma.max(marr))
# >>>1.0    # since the mask tells mask to ignore the nan. The max of the rest (0,1) is 1.
```

Comment: Right, you made a masked array but did not tell it what values you did not want.  The np.isnan(arr) bit tells the masked array what data you don't want.  If you don't tell it how is numpy to know what is good and what is not. Cyborg has it just right.  What I don't quite get is why print(np.max(marr)) also prints 1.  What is np.ma.max for?  I never use it.

Comment: @Brian Larsen , masked arrays are a more sophisticated way of doing what nanmax does, because they allow you to skip not just nans, but  other irregular types, e.g. inf.

Comment: @Cyborg True enough, my point is that the behavior of np.max and np.ma.max seem identical on a masked array (masking whatever it is you want to mask: NaN, -999, or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way to create the mask is to use the np.ma.masked_invalid function (see. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_invalid.html#numpy.ma.masked_invalid)

Here is an example:

```
# Makes example reproducible 
np.random.seed(seed=1337)
# Generate some data
X = np.random.random((5,5))
X[X > .5] = np.nan
print X
array([[ 0.26202468,  0.15868397,  0.27812652,  0.45931689,  0.32100054],
       [        nan,  0.26194293,         nan,         nan,  0.11527423],
       [ 0.38627507,         nan,  0.12505793,         nan,  0.44322487],
       [        nan,         nan,  0.36126157,  0.41610394,         nan],
       [        nan,  0.18780841,  0.28816715,         nan,  0.49964826]])
# Mask will hide both np.nan and np.inf values
masked_X = np.ma.masked_invalid(X, copy=False)
# Voila
print np.max(masked_X, axis=0)
masked_array(data = [0.38627506863435945 0.26194292556514465 0.36126157241743073
 0.45931688721456665 0.49964826137201246],
             mask = [False False False False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```